# Библиотека не находит шаблон html файла

Tags: golang, шаблоны, render, fiber

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, что означают первый и третий параметры в методе *Render* библиотеки *[fiber/template](https://github.com/gofiber/template)* (*Go*)? Причем третий параметр, судя по примерам, вообще можно не указывать.

```
c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
            "Title": "Hello, World!",
        }, "layouts/main")
```

Что ни указываю - `template not found`.
Настройки создаю так:

```
engine := html.New("../assets/templates", ".html")
```

Само приложение находится в каталоге `bin` (ну, так на *heroku* нужно - автоматически создается этот каталог с собранным приложением). А вся статика у меня в каталоге `assets`. Каталог `assets` находится на одном уровне с каталогом `bin` (не внутри него), где  и находится сам *exe*'шник.
В итоге, не понимаю что указывать в этих параметрах:

`c.Render("auth", data, "auth")`

`auth.html` у меня лежит в `assets/templates`.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в указании пути.

```
engine := html.New("./assets/templates", ".html")
```

Ну а в Render первым параметром идет имя шаблона, которое должно было быть указано в начале шаблона: {{define "auth"}}, третий параметр, уточняющий путь относительно базового каталога шаблонов, скорей всего здесь и вовсе не нужен.